# Windows 8 App with Facebook Login returning error "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login, windows-8.1

I'm creating a Windows Store App using WinJS and Facebook Login. I've implemented Facebook Login using the recommended method described on Facebook Developer site for Windows 8 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/).

I've also updated my application settings in Facebook by entering my Package Security Identifier (SID) into the Windows Store ID field.

The problem is that when I launch the application, and click login, I am getting the following message:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

I've encountered this issue when creating websites with Facebook Login, it was simply a matter of adding the correct domain to the Facebook Application settings. But as this is a native app, there isn't an actual domain that I can use is there?

Below is a sample of my code that's executed when the "login" button is clicked.

var doLogin = function() {

```
        var requestUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[[FACEBOOK_APP_ID]]&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=ms-app://[[SID_ENTERED_HERE]]");
        var options = { scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_location' }

        Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(
          options,
          requestUri)
          .done(function (response) {
               // handle response
          }
        );
```

}

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Facebook the SID of your application. You do this on the Facebook app developer page. Click apps, and then choose Basic. Below the basic section, click "Add Platform" and then choose Windows App. Then you will have a dialog where you can enter your "Windows Store ID". Once I put my SID in here and clicked save the WebAuthenticationBroker started working.

(I also enabled the "Native or desktop app" toggle under Advanced, but I don't know if that was relevant to it starting to work or not.)